# Express vector of inner product polynomials as matrix (decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I would like to express the following product of the vectors $\theta=(\theta_0,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_\nu)$ and $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_p)$ where $p$ does not necessarily equal $\nu+1$.

$$  \begin{bmatrix}
        \sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_1^k\\
        \sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_2^k\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_p^k
    \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
        \theta (x_1^0,x_1^1,\ldots,x_1^\nu )^\top\\
        \theta (x_2^0,x_2^1,\ldots,x_2^\nu )^\top\\
\vdots\\
\theta (x_p^0,x_p^1,\ldots,x_p^\nu )^\top
    \end{bmatrix}$$

The reason I would like to do this is ultimately I would like to solve for $\theta$ in the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\\vdots\\y_p\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
        \sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_1^k\\
        \sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_2^k\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_p^k
    \end{bmatrix}$$
when $X$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_p)$ are known.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it, or at least realized the limitations of my question.
$$  \begin{bmatrix}
        \sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_1^k\\
        \sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_2^k\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{k=0}^\nu \theta_k x_p^k
    \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
        \theta_0 &\theta_1&\ldots &\theta_\nu
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        (x_1)^0 &(x_2)^0 &\ldots&(x_p)^0\\
        (x_1)^1 &(x_2)^1 &\ldots&(x_p)^1\\
\vdots\\
(x_1)^\nu &(x_2)^\nu &\ldots&(x_p)^\nu
    \end{bmatrix}=\theta P
$$
where $P$ is of dimension $\nu+1\times p$.

Comment: It should be $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1 & \cdots & x_1^\nu\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1 & x_p & \cdots& x_p^\nu\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\theta_0\\\vdots\\\theta_\nu\end{pmatrix} = P\theta$$.